# I want to know what config options were used to compile apache?

Tags: apache2

My apache server crashes due to some segmentation fault. I tried to debug it by compiling the apache from source. Now the crash seems to be gone with this new apache (I tried many times to reproduce the crash.) I compiled the apache from source using some config options helpful for debugging. I want to know what config options were used to compile the apache if i install it from binary? 
I am using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3):

`apache2 -V`  Print the version and build parameters of apache2, and then exit. ([source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apache2.8.html))